# Poisson log-likelihood is concave but not Lipschitz-continuous?

Tags: poisson-regression, concavity, differentiable

According to [He et al. (2016)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.01264), the log-likelihood of Poisson models,
$$
 L (\beta) = \sum_{i} - \log(x_{i}^{\mathsf{T}}\beta) + y_{i}x_{i}^{\mathsf{T}}\beta - \log y_{i}!
$$
for a random variable, $y_{i} \sim \text{Pois}(x_{i}^\mathsf{T}\beta) $, is *"known to be non-globally Lipschitz continuous or differentiable"* (p. 2).  Apparently this result is so well-known that it does not require a citation.  Does anyone know where this was shown?

Comment: (If you are going to criticise lack of citation, make sure you give page numbers for your own citations.)  I have edited your question to add this.  ; )

Comment: Alright, thanks. The same statement actually appears in the abstract, too.